# How to expose a API that is running in a Pod and limit access?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an API running in a service in my GKE Cluster and it needs to be accessible for some other developers in my team. They are using a VPN so they have a static IP they can provide to me.

My idea was to just expose the service using a static external IP and restricting access to this IP using a Firewall rule so just the IP of my colleagues.

Unfortunately this just seems to be possible for Compute-VMs because only they can have tags.

Is there a way how I can simply deny all traffic to my service except for traffic from the specific IP?

I appreciate any hints to features, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't need tags, you can create your firewall rule to only allow access to the IP your developers provide you, just when you're creating your firewall rule, select **all instances in the network** for *Targets* and for *source IP ranges* specify the **IP with the prefix /32 at the end**.

Comment: That solution sounds like what I was looking for, Thank you! My issue is: If I create an external IP for the service it is immediately accessible for everyone which I don't want. For the service type I used LoadBalancer. Could that be the wrong kind of service for my usecase? What type of service or other solution would you recommen?

Comment: Well.. You could set some allow/disallow rules on IP ranges through Google's Cloud Armor Security Policies by setting the target on the backend service of an HTTP load balancer, check this guide.
https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies.

Answer (score 1):

You could provide them RBAC access to the pods in the required namespace and allow them to port forward.  Assuming you don't want to set up a public end point and try secure it. This does require kubectl to be installed and cluster access and this will give access to all pods in the namespace.

https://medium.com/@ManagedKube/kubernetes-rbac-port-forward-4c7eb3951e28

Depends what level of security and permanency you need I guess.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I'm still looking for a better solution though. Thank you